# Code Clone Benchmarking Tool for Python

Tags: python, benchmarking

I'm in a research group working on a tool to detect code clones in Python. For clarification, a code clone is a pair of code snippets which are similar, if not exactly the same. We need a way to test our tool - a benchmark of existing Python clones which we can run our tool against. A similar tool for Java already exists - [BigCloneBench](https://github.com/clonebench/BigCloneBench). We have the following requirements:

- Clones must be in Python
- Clones must be identified by the tool as [type 1, 2, or 3](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3381307.3381310) (see section 2.2)
- Clones must be syntactic, not [semantic](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9047643)

Per my last source, such a tool doesn't exist as of March 2020. I'm hoping someone here knows of any active efforts to produce it or knows something they overlooked. We have had no luck in our search so far. Additionally, this is my first post here, so please tell me if there is a better place to put this question.